# How to disable autoindent on new line?

Tags: spacemacs, indentation

I find a lot of questions similar to this, but not one with an answer that matches what I need.  I'm using spacemacs in evil mode, and I want "new lines" (done with RET in insert mode, or o or O etc) to either:

1. Just appear with no indentation at all, just like I'm used to in vim

or

2. Appear with exactly the whitespace prefix of the line that precedes them

How can I acheive one of these?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what is bound to <kbd>RET</kbd> or <kbd>return</kbd>in the mode you're looking to modify (note that this key in particular might be different in terminal or graphical environment).

To know what is bound to use <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>h</kbd> <kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd>. You'll learn what function is bound, on what key map it was asked, and bound function documentation.

For example if it's bound to `(newline)` and `Electric-Indent` minor mode is enabled you may want it bound to `electric-indent-just-newline`. This can be achieved with:

```lisp
 (define-key found-mode-map (kbd "<return>") 'electric-indent-just-newline)
```

As rule of thumb it's a better idea making changes exactly where you need them using the specific mode map key than modifiying the global map.

Answer (score 0):

To get (1), just disable `electric-indent-mode`, e.g. with:

```
(electric-indent-mode -1)
```

To get (2), it depends on exactly why and when (e.g. in all buffers, or only in `org-mode` but not in `rust-mode`, ...) you want that and how you want it to interact with TAB-indentation.

Comment: I already have `(electric-indent-mode -1)`

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be working for me:

```
(defun singpolyma/indent-line ()
    "Don't auto indent lines."
    )

(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
    ...
    (add-hook 'prog-mode-hook (lambda ()
        (setq indent-line-function 'singpolyma/indent-line)
    ))
    (add-hook 'text-mode-hook (lambda ()
        (setq indent-line-function 'singpolyma/indent-line)
    ))
    ...
)
```

Comment: That may work, but doesn't comply with `indent-line-function` documentation.

Comment: @Muihlinn curious how not?  Documentation says this function is called when a line should be indented.  This function does nothing, thus effectively disabling the indentation feature.

Comment: Perhaps I'm being overzealous here, but part of `indent-line-function` tells that
"If it is called somewhere where auto-indentation cannot be done (e.g. inside a string), the function should simply return ‘noindent’."